# What's the relashionship between the network-root-truststore and nodekeystore?

Tags: corda

Why does the Node need the network-root-truststore.jks file at initial registration? What's the relashionship between this file and the nodekeystore.jks?

> EDIT: Actually, I was meant that I didn't see the relashionship between the CSR and the network-root-truststore.jks file. Is it not possible to generate the Certificate Signing Request without this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`network-root-truststore.jks`-> This is the network operator's root CA.

`nodekeystore.jks` -> This contains nodes identity key pairs and certificates.

[image: Permissioning]
As you can see in the diagram. The Root CA for Doorman and Network Map are same. The node assumes 3 level hierarchy as you can see in the picture above. ( This got fixed in version 3.3 so you can have a n-level certificate hierarchy)

For initial registration with the doorman, you'd need to create a CSR request and send it to the doorman, the doorman will then return you the requestId, Using the provided requestId you'll ask the doorman if the CSR has been signed by him or not once done, Doorman will hand you over the node certificate like below

[image: Node Certificate]

Once you've the node certificate signed by the doorman, you want to validate it (for this you'd need the RootCA Certificate which is inside the `network-root-truststore.jks` now you don't need it to create the CSR, but the certificate received must be validated, as result, you need this. Also, this prevents man in the middle attack.)and generate the TLS key pair and certificates.

**The above process is automatically done by the corda node for you at the time of initial registration when you start the node using this command** -> `java -jar corda.jar --initial-registration --network-root-truststore-password <trust store password>`

**One Important thing is you should remove or delete the `network-root-truststore.jks` file once you are done with the registration.**

Comment: Hi @Kid101, thanks for the detailed response. Actually, what I meant was that, investigating the unit testing code, I didn't see the relationship between the CSR and the network-root-truststore.jks. To be more specific, the submitOrResumeCertificateSigningRequest() function in NetworkRegistrationHelper.kt. I'll edit the question to better clarify.

Comment: updated. check the link where the where it' s used.
https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/106eb9df4a74317f7775b04b77bf087fcf163b76/node/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/node/utilities/registration/NetworkRegistrationHelper.kt#L163

Comment: the `rootCert` is your RootCA present in network-root-truststore.jks. check the init method there